# Neural Network with images as input and single pixels output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to train a NN that should return a single pixel image having as input 90x90 images.
Dataset consists of 1000 RGB images in a numpy array, so shape is (1000, 90, 90, 3) for input, and the target output contains 1000 RGB images made by the brightest pixel in each image, so the shape is (1000, 1, 1, 3).

The fitting of the model seems to work good, with reasonable loss values, but when I run prediction I get an output with 90x90 images.

I've tryed different kind of models using Conv2D layers, Dense layer, MaxPooling2D and mixing them in different way with different parameters, but I can't get a 1x1 output.

EDIT
I've tryed the way BestDogeStackoverflow suggested, and I think it works. Here the network:

```
def create_model():
    x = Input(shape=(64,64,3))# Encoder
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(pool1)    
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(pool2)    
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(pool3)    
    pool5 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(pool4)
    pool6 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(pool5)   
    r = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='linear', padding='same')(pool6)  
    model = Model(x, r)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    return model
    
model = create_model()
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.MeanSquaredError())
```

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                batch_size=10,
                epochs=20,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Now the prediction shape is what expected:

```
predict = encoder.predict(
    X_test, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None, callbacks=None, max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False)

print (predict.shape)
```

(330, 1, 1, 3)

Is it ok that model.summary() returns this?

```
Model: "model_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 12
Trainable params: 12
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Why do you want a neural network to return the brightest pixel? Can't you just search the pixels in each image for the brightest pixel?

Comment: Of course, and it would be easier, but it's the first step of a project and I have to use a NN.

Comment: Hard to tell unless you post your network definition.

Comment: You should post your network code since the error probably occurs in your neural network architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an image of 1x1 as an output (that really sound like something nobody would want to do in ANY circumstances) you need to use a fully convolutional neural network with layers that reduce the image dimension, you need to use layers like traspose convolutions and maxpooling to reduce the dimension to 1, but 90x90 wont work, you need to resize your image  to have dimension as a power of 2, (so something like 128x128 or 64x64), then use enough maxpooling until you reach the 1x1 dimension for the output.

Comment: an other method to get to 128x128 would be to add a pad of 38 black pixels to your 90x90 image on both dimensions, this way  you will not have to interpolate the values of the pixels

Comment: to get to 1x1 from a 128x128 you will need 7 layers of maxpooling

Comment: I used 64x64 and copied the code above. Seems ok

Comment: ok good, mark it as solution then, this way the answer appear solved and closed